# Handlebars - nested templates

Tags: templates, nested, handlebars.js

Is it possible to defined nested templates in Handlebars:

```
<script id="template-parent" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <some markup here ...>
  <script id="template-child" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <some markup from nested template here ... >
  </script>
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

Handlebars has a built-in helper called "partials" that will allow you to include a fragment of a template from elsewhere.  See https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html